# Migration from godaddy server to other server

Tags: wordpress, migration

I have the WordPress hosting on GoDaddy and today I tried to migrate it, but after completing the migration steps it started to show a 500 error. I already enabled the debugging on `wp-config` file:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

I also enabled the debugging feature of WordPress.

Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue?

Comment: try deleting .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Check .Httaccess
Change value in wp_options : **siteurl** & **home**
Database information in wp-config.php

Comment: i tried that but that is not working on my platform.

Answer (score 0):

what i always use to migrate any wordpress project is [wp-clone](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/)